# Return the count of all records per day of week by clientId

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that will return the daily count of clients records (for the last 7 days) by client.

Given a table with the following significant fields:

```
ClientId,    ProcessTime,
```

I'd like to produce a table with the clientId and the last 7 days as column headers 0 - 7 (including today) and the records processed in that day:

```
ClientId, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
```

I have come up with the following query which gets me close:

```
Select ClientId, Count(Id) as [Count], max(DATEDIFF(DAY,ProcessTime,GETDATE())) as [Day]
from CallRecords
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,ProcessTime,GETDATE()) <= 7
group by ClientId, Dateadd(day, Datediff(day, 0, ProcessTime), 0)
order by 1, 2
```

which produces:

```
ClientId Count Day 
1        60    0
1        4707  1
1        11613 2
```

However, how can I manipulate those results into a format where I get a list of clients and the last 7 days of results as columns?

Comment: It's a PIVOT you need.

Comment: Ok thanks, PIVOT is new to me, ill see what i come up with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want what is termed a [*pivot*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table), which SQLServer natively supports:

```
select ClientId, [0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7]
from (select ClientId, DATEDIFF(DAY,ProcessTime,GETDATE()) days
    from CallRecords
    where DATEDIFF(DAY,ProcessTime,GETDATE()) <= 7) t
pivot (count(days) for days in ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])) pt
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/71cc7/6)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ClientID 
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,ProcessTime) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Sunday]
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,ProcessTime) = 2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Monday]
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,ProcessTime) = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Tuesday]
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,ProcessTime) = 4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Wednesday]
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,ProcessTime) = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Thursday]
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,ProcessTime) = 6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Friday]
      ,COUNT(CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,ProcessTime) = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS [Saturday]
FROM CallRecords
WHERE ProcessTime >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()) - 7, 0) 
GROUP BY ClientID
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that looks like it hits the mark, ill leave this open for a while just to see if there are any other solutions while i play with your wonderfull query

Comment: (1) DW is lazy shorthand that can lead to ambiguity or incorrect results - [spell it out](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations); (2) `GETDATE() - 7` is also lazy shorthand that will break if they later change to newer date types (see same article); (3) If it is datetime then I think you would want to cut off at midnight, otherwise you get different results for the first day in the range depending on what time of day the query is run.

Comment: @AaronBertrand a question for you please, What do you reckon a requirement like this better done using PIVOT query on this method? Is any one method preferred over other performance wise??

Comment: PIVOT is certainly cleaner, you don't have all these repeated and cumbersome `COUNT(CASE)` expressions. Doubt there's much difference performance-wise, but you could test that.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot is the way to go for this scenario.  Here is a link to Microsofts pivot documentation, [Microsoft PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).  To find the day of the week you should use the DatePart function, [Microsoft DatePart Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

```
select ClientId as 'Client', [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7] from (
    select ClientId, Id, CAST(DatePart(dw,ProcessTime) as int) as [DayOfWeek]
    from CallRecords
) as SourceTable
PIVOT (
    COUNT(Id)
    FOR [DayOfWeek] IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7])
) as pvt
```

[Checkout this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6697e9/46/0)